# Book Recommendation: One that has a lot of problems and theory associated with polar coordinates and spherical polar coordinates

Tags: vectors, book-recommendation, electromagnetism

I would like to **"master"** polar coordinates and spherical polar coordinates. In the sense, I would like to become as well versed with them as I am with cartesian coordinates.

I have gone through many physics books, Boas, Marsfield, Griffiths, but they really don't get into this stuff deep enough. For instance, I just don't have any intuition for unit vectors (r, theta), the fact that they can keep changing as a particle moves along a certain trajectory troubles me greatly. I simply cannot "see" these vectors.

In truth, I may be able to solve problems, but I lack understanding and insight.

Hence, this request. My ultimate goal: (1) To be able to truly appreciate the full power of these coordinate systems -- when, why, and how to use them, especially in the context of Classical Mechanics, Electrodynamics, and Quantum Mechanics.

In other words, I would appreciate book(s) that treat(s) the above coordinate systems with great rigour, so that I may be able to invoke them with impunity in the areas of physics. I do not want any book(s) that treat the above with "lazy" rigour as I see most physics books do.

So, please give me titles of books that truly discuss the above in detail, and not just burn through them without giving them their due diligence, as most applied mathematics/mathematical physics/engineering books I know of.

Comment: I know only one problem, but maybe you can find it interesting: given two independent random variables U and V that follow the uniform distribution on [0, 1], write the formula for a random variable describing a uniformly random point on the unit sphere (using the coordinate system of your choice). And of course also write a proof that this formula is correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have yet to find a book discussing spherical coordinates in the rigorous manner you are asking for. Regardless I can share other books/resources that discuss this coordinate system and apply it to quantum mechanics. Seeing some more images and calculations might show the spherical coordinate system's usefulness and help your intuition.

I would advise you to solve the Schrödinger equation for a hydrogen atom with cartesian and spherical coordinates separately. I believe this would convince you why spherical coordinates are easier to use for spherical symmetric systems.

Here is a general calculus book, definitely not in debt or rigorous. Either way it might be a different point of view.

1. Adams, R. A., & Essex, C. (2016). Calculus: A Complete Course (9th ed.). Prentice Hall. (p.605-607)

Here are some more chemistry-related books that show spherical harmonics and or hydrogen-like orbitals:

1. Efthimiou, C., & Frye, C. (2014). Spherical harmonics in P dimensions. World Scientific Publishing Company Incorporated. (p.1-12)
2. Atkins, P. W., De Paula, J., & Keeler, J. (2018). Atkins’ physical chemistry (11th ed.). Oxford University Press. (p.285-287)
3. Oxtoby, D. W., Gillis, H. P., & Butler, L. J. (2015). Principles of modern chemistry (8th ed.). Brooks Cole. (p.178-194)

These websites might also be helpful:

1. [LibreTexts, Spherical Coordinates](https://chem.libretexts.org/Bookshelves/Physical_and_Theoretical_Chemistry_Textbook_Maps/Physical_Chemistry_(LibreTexts)/32%3A_Math_Chapters/32.04%3A_Spherical_Coordinates)
2. [Medium, Mathematics for Quantum Mechanics: Coordinate Systems](https://organized-curiosity.medium.com/mathematics-for-quantum-mechanics-coordinate-systems-c50c85428892)
3. [Mathematics for Quantum Physics, Coordinate systems](https://mathforquantum.quantumtinkerer.tudelft.nl/2_coordinates/#25-problems)

---

As a final note, the notation for the azimuthal and polar angles is not standard. Mathematicians typically use $\theta$ and $\phi$ respectively while Physicists do it the other way around.

Comment: Thank you so much. Could you please help me choose which book has the best and most detailed treatment of the same? Or do I read all these books simultaneously.

Furthermore, I would be greatly indebted to you if you could share books that are more physics-y? Electrodynamics in particular?

Comment: @S_M Classical Electrodynamics by John David Jackson does cover multiple coordinate systems. But again, I am not sure it is as rigorous as you are asking for. Principles of Modern Chemistry covers a bit more about spherical coordinates than Atkins'. Purely for polar coordinates, you shouldn't buy Principles or Atkins' because they are not focused on that in any way. The calculus book is also quite short in the treatment of spherical coordinates. I think the Spherical harmonics one should have a good review in the introduction. I'll update the post when I find other books.

Answer (score 1):

I recall my first experience with a "crash course" in vector calculus that included introduction to cylindrical coordinates and spherical coordinates.  The professor presented several heuristic developments in that course, especially when discussing topics such as the divergence theorem and Stokes' theorem.

So to address your quest, almost any text book on Vector Calculus will suffice. For example, "Introduction to Vector Analysis," by Davis and Snider has an entire chapter dedicated to Generalized Orthogonal Coordinates, which contains a separate section on cylindrical and spherical coordinates.

In addition, many books on Advanced Calculus will also contains chapters on vector analysis.  The book "Advanced Calculus," by John Olmsted, for example, has a chapter on vector analysis with separate sections on curvilnear coordinates and orthogonal coordinates.  Those sections cover cylindrical and spherical coordinates.

These were only two examples out of a voluminous set of references that one can find with a literature review.  Best of luck in your pursuits.

Comment: @S_M It's considered bad form to accept an answer and then reverse the acceptance.

Comment: I am sorry, I had forgotten that I had accepted this answer. I thought I had not closed it. So, I simply accepted the first answer without scrolling down. Apologies. Both answers were great, hence, I, in order to be be done with this task asap, clicked on the "first" tick that I came across.

What would you like me to do? Do you wish me to "untick" the previous answer and accept this one, instead?

Comment: @S_M Thank you for the thoughtful reply.  You may do as you choose.  Happy Holidays!